# Incrementing a setInterval() value from a global

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to increment the timeout on either setInterval, or setTimout. However, my global is not working. I'm not to familiar with javascript. Please help!

```
//What I'm trying to do:

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var joeIncrement=1;
    setInterval(function() {
    joeIncrement++;
    $('#comment_counter').load('get_commentcount.php');
    }, 15000*joeIncrement);
});
```

Comment: _"... on either setInterval, or setTimout"_ -- You want `setTimeout`.

Comment: _I'm not to familiar with javascript._ [Let me introduce it to you](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var joeIncrement=1;
    var interval = function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            joeIncrement++;
            $('#comment_counter').load('get_commentcount.php');
            interval();
        }, 15000*joeIncrement);
    }
    interval(joeIncrement)
});
```